# Instance member 'playerID' cannot be used on type 'GKPlayer'

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm beginning to implement Game Center in my iOS app, and I would like to use the player ID as my unique identifier elsewhere in the app. However, when I try to declare a variable:

```
var playerID: String? { GKPlayer.playerID }
```

I get the error `Instance member 'playerID' cannot be used on type 'GKPlayer'.` Looking through Game Center docs I didn't find anything that could help me (but could easily be me, not the docs). Is there some code I need to execute before declaring playerID? This is all being done after I authenticate the local player, fwiw.

Do I need to use `loadPlayers(forIdentifiers:withCompletionHandler:)` to get the ID of a single, local user?

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but how do I do that?

Comment: Okay so it sounds like I do need to use `loadPlayers(forIdentifiers:withCompletionHandler:)` to do this. Will see if I can get that going. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the player objects first, then you can look up the playerID for each. `loadPlayers` isn't going to help because you have to already know the playerIDs you want when you call loadPlayers.

There are two places you can get the player objects. First, there's the "local player" that's logged into Game Center on the device. Second, both real-time and turn-based matches contain a list of all players participating in that match at that instant.

I don't know swift syntax, but in obj-c, getting the local player's ID looks like:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
NSString *playerID = localPlayer.playerID
```

The match object will have the array of objects for the entire set of players in that match. In a realtime, `GKMatch` object, the property is called `players`. In a turn-based `GKTurnBasedMatch` object, the property is called `participants`. Getting the list of participants in a turn-based match, for example, looks like:

```
for (GKTurnBasedMatchParticipant *participant in match.participants)
{
     GKPlayer *player = participant.player;
     NSString *playerID = player.playerID;
}
```

Note that in turn-based matches, when you create a match for, say, 6 players, the creator (the local player) takes the first slot. Participants 2-6 will be empty until those players actually join the game (on their first turn).

Once you have the playerID, you can use it as an identifier in the rest of your code. Later, if you want to look up details about a player, you can call `loadPlayers` using the playerID you want to look up.

Comment: Declaring `var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()` and `var playerID = localPlayer.playerID` works syntactically, but returns a nil `playerID` for a signed in user.  The name is `me` (which is expected for `localPlayer`) but `alias` and `playerID` in the `localPlayer` array are both nil.

Comment: Figured it out. I was declaring `playerID` before authentication finished. Got what I needed, thanks very much!